# How to embed external backend content to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a front end website using Wordpress that I wanted to display some data from our backend website on.

I am having trouble figuring out how to set it up. In theory I could iframe a small part onto the page to list a small table on it but then the table formatted data would not be searchable from my wordpress search. Does anyone have any recommendations? My data that I want to embed could be anything I want to return but usually it will be text. It could be JSON, HTML, etc.

I have a feeling my only option would be to build a sync function that imports all my backend data to the wordpress database to then call into my page.

Comment: You haven't described what kind of data do you need to display. Is options, posts, meta-data or custom database data or something else?

Comment: Sorry I'll edit the question. The data can be anything I return from my backend query, usually a text based response, JSON, HTML, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task consist of this parts:

**Import data** from your backend website. There are couple of ways to
   that: if your backend website has a kind of API you can access data using [wp_remote_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) or use files for exchange data
   (backend upload and frontend website read the file).

**Save data** in the WP. Here you can use [WP Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) Or you can use [wpdb object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to interact with WP database.

**Display data** using [Shorcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Depended on size of your data, it may be possible to skip step two and display imported data without storing.

Comment: The wp_remote_get might be perfect for what I am looking for. Do you know if that content will get indexed in a search?

Comment: @Mike, depended on how you implement display of data. Do you need it to be indexed or not?

Comment: In my case I am looking to have it indexed.

Comment: So, you need to create a new shortcode for displaying data and add this shorcode to the page of website available for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about having that content indexed in the WP search, you could use the wpdb class.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb